# Parse foursquare json response on android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am trying to parse the JSON file returned by Foursquare API on android.The JSON fle starts like this:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"groups":[{"type":"places","name":"Matching Places","items":[{"id":"4bc5b8056936952188618488","name":"Boots Clifton Down","contact":{},
```

and here is my function so far:

```
    private void tokenize(String output){   
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);
            JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("groups").getJSONArray("items");
            System.out.println(venues.length());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
```

I tried replacing

```
JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("groups").getJSONArray("items");
```

with

```
JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("groups").getJSONArray("items");
```

but I keep getting

```
org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
```

I am trying to create a JSONArray from the `items` array. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("response")
  .getJSONArray("groups")
  .getJSONObject(0)
  .getJSONArray("items");
```

Comment: Assuming you're only interested in the first group.

Comment: This will get you a better stacktrace as well. When they're all on one line, it becomes more difficult to find your offending statement.