# android json parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

```
[
{
    "user": {
        "active": true,
        "admin": false
    }
},
{
    "user": {
        "active": true,
        "admin": true
    }
},
{
    "user": {
        "active": false,
        "admin": false
    }
},
{
    "user": {
        "active": false,
        "admin": false
    }
}
]
```

The above is my JSON that I am trying to parse.
Below is what I believe to be a relevant portion of my code

```
//The entire thing is an array  
JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(bufferedandappended);

for(int i=0; i<array2.length(); i++){
    String name = array2.getJSONObject(i).getString("user");
    tv2.setText(sb.toString());
```

Instead of all four users' info, I only get one. How would I be able to list all four.

I think the whole is array2 and the four users are arrays within array2. Am I correct? If so, how would I for example, only choose to print the values of "admin" of the four users?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130510/parse-foursquare-json-response-on-android

Comment: Thanks Samir. Using this info, I got it to work partially. I realized that the whole thing was an array before they are objects because of []. So i tried that.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is **Invalid JSON**. I have tested via [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)
2. You are trying to fetch realusers object through the below code:

   JSONObject responseOBJ = mResponseObject.getJSONObject("realusers");

But **There is no "realusers" in your JSON response string.**

Comment: Hey Paresh, thanks for your input. I edited a lot of things because I got it to work partially. Please let me know if you have any input